# Overriding base class methods in template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have base template class and I'm creating derived class from it which is template specialization of base class. Base class has a virtual method which I'm trying to overload in derived class and I get the compile error. In fact, I'm not sure whether the way I'm doing is correct or not.

```
template <class T>
struct BasicContext
{
  BasicContext() {}
  bool operator() (const T i) const
  {
    return isValid(i);
  }
  virtual bool isValid(const T) const
  {
    return true;
  }
  virtual BasicContext* Clone() const
  {
    return(new BasicContext<T>());
  }
};

class Myclass
{
 public:
 Myclass()
 {
 }
};
class MyclassContext : public BasicContext<Myclass*>
{
 public:
 MyclassContext();
 bool isValid(const Myclass* bdry) const override; 
 BasicContext* Clone() const override;
};
```

And my cpp files looks like this:

```
bool MyclassContext::isValid(const Myclass* m) const
{
  return true;
}
BasicContext<Myclass*>* MyclassContext::Clone() const
{
   return new MyclassContext();
}
```

I do get the following compile error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C3668   'MyclassContext::isValid': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods    DbgError    F:\C++\DbgError\DbgError\Dummy.h    36

Basically the `isValid` method is not recognized as a base class method in the derived class. How can I override the base class method `isValid` in the derived class with specialized parameter type? I mean what should be the parameter type?

Comment: Misplaced `const`.   In `MyclassContext`, do `bool isValid(Myclass* const bdry) const override` instead.     The difference between `const Myclass *` and `Myclass * const` is what the `const` affects - the former it is a pointer to a `const Myclass`, the latter is a `const` pointer which can point at a non-`const` instance of `Myclass`.   Better yet, since your function is accepting argument by value, remove the `const` entirely from the argument (it has no useful effect in your template or in derived classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that in your base class' `isValid(const T)` method the `const` is **top-level** but in your derived class' `isValid(const Myclass* m)`, you've provided a **low-level const**.

Basically, ***when overriding methods the top-level const must remain top-level and low-level const must remain low-level***.

##### Solution

Thus to solve this, change `const Myclass* m` to `Myclass* constm` as shown below:

```
//-------------------vvvvv---------------------->moved const here
bool isValid(Myclass*const bdry) const override;
```

---

Make sure you do this in both the declaration and definition of `isValid`.